# 2 ui-view confused index page and modal window angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a big problem,

In my program I have 2 ui-view, the first to display the page (connection, calendar, ...) it is in index.html and the second to load the menu in my modal, this one is in agenda.html,

First I do not understand why my view ui-view = 'main' does not load my file menu.html and secondly if my file is loading I want to navigate in the same ui-view (when I click 'Route 1' , It shows me the result in the view = main, etc ....)

This is my route:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){    
      $stateProvider
          .state("foo", {
              url: "/foo",
              template: '<h1>foo</h1>'
          })
          .state("menu", {
              url: "/menu",
              templateUrl: 'menu.html'
          })
          .state("bar", {
              url: "/bar",
              template: '<h1>bar</h1>'
          })

          .state("connexion", {
              url: "/",
              templateUrl: 'connexion.html'
          })

          .state('agenda', {

            url: "/agenda",
            views: {

                // for column two, we'll define a separate controller
                '': {

                    abstract :true,
                    templateUrl: 'agenda.html'

                },
                'main':{

                    abstract :true,
                    templateUrl: 'menu.html'

                }
            }


        })

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

    })
```

This is an plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/Zyrj3gRv1cGZpcWwhXfL?p=preview

If someone can help me please,  I am really stuck.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I put the menu in the modal but my first view '' Principal'' disappears

this is the new plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/3tc42NIi4E41NPyAFy8w?p=preview

Comment: Why do you have the menu as a separate state? usually the menu lives on the main page and is not part of a particular state (you wont redirect people to menu but rather use it to redirect them to elsewhere)

Comment: this one is an example , in my reality programs i have a menu and in this modal i have a choice for formulaire ( example : 1 for inscription , 2 for info , ...)